# Java: How to cut the third word out of a string?

Tags: java

I want to single out the third word of an inputted String and save it to a new variable. Any pointers as to the method I could use for this?

Most wanted more information, so the program is for cutting up a product title and distributing the keywords to fill in the blanks of a html metadata block I wrote. The first word in the title is always the manufacturer of the model, the second is the manufacturer of the car, the third is the make of the car. I have written code for all car and model manufacturers, with the .contains method, but the car makes are far too various and extensive, leaving me needing just to cut the word out of the title and save it straight to the variable. The only code I can give you is what I have so far in the program because I don't even know where to start with cutting up an inputted string.

This is what I have so far:

import java.util.Scanner;
public class MetagenV3 {

```
private static boolean keepRunning;

public static void main (String[] args) {

    do {
    GenerateData(); }
    while (keepRunning = true);
    if (keepRunning = false) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

    public static void GenerateData() {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String title = null;
    String abstr = "Shop for diecast model cars at [SITE REMOVED]";
    String scale = null;
    String diecastManu = null;
    String metaModel = null;
    String metaMake = null;
    String defaultstring = "quality";

    String[] metaMakesList = {"Abarth", "Acura", "Ahrens", "Alfa Romeo"
            +"Alpine Renault", "AMC", "American LaFrance", "Aprilia", "Aston Martin" 
            +"Audi", "Austin", "Austin-Healey", "Bedford", "Benelli", "Bentley", "BMW"
            +"Buffalo", "Bugatti", "Buick","Cadillac","Caterham", "Chaparrel"
            + "Checker","Chevrolet","Chrysler","Citroen", "Cleveland", "Cord","DAF"
            + "Daimler","Dakota","Datsun","Dauer","De Soto", "Delahaye", "DeLorean", "Dennis", "Divco"
            + "Dodge", "Duesenberg", "Edsel", "F1", "Ferrari","Fiat","Ford","Freightliner"
            +"GAZ", "GMC", "Gumpert", "Halo", "Helicopter","Hello Kitty", "Honda","Horch","Hudson"
            + "Hummer","Hyundai","Infiniti", "International", "Jaguar", "Jeep", "K2", "Kaiser"
            + "Koenigsegg","Lamborghini","Lancia","Land Rover", "LandRover", "Lexus","Leyland"
            + "Lincoln", "Lotus","Mack","Magirus-Deutz","Maserati","Maxim", "Maybach"
            + "Mazda","McLaren","Mercedes-Benz","Mercedes Benz","Mercedes","Mercury","Messerschmitt"
            +"Meyers Manxter","MG","Mini","Mini Cooper","Mitsubishi","Morgan","Morris"
            + "Nash", "Nissan","Oldsmobile","Opel","Packard","Pagani","Panhard","Panoz","Pantera"
            + "Peugeot","Pierce-Arrow","Plymouth","Pontiac","Porsche","Puegoet","Renault","Reo"
            + "Rolls Royce", "Rolls-Royce","Saturn","Scion","Seagrave","Seat","Simca", "Smart"
            + "Studebaker","Stutz", "Subaru","Tata","Toyota","Triumph","Tucker","TVR","TX1"
            + "VolksWagen","Volvo","White","Willys"};

    String[] scaleList = {"1:12","1:18","1:24","1:32","1:43","1:64","1/12", "1/18", "1/24", "1/32", "1/43", "1/64"};

    String[] diecastManuList = {"Muscle Machines","Jada Toys"
                    +"AUTOart","Kinsmart","M2","1BaddRide"
                    +"Greenlight","Anson","Arko","Auto World"
                    +"Bauer","BBR","BBurago","Carney Plastics"
                    +"Collectable Diecast","CMC","Double Horse"
                    +"Elvis Motor Classics","Classic Metal Works"
                    +"Ertl","Fast Women","First Gear","GMP","Hawk"
                    +"Highway 61","Hot Wheels","Hot Works","IXO"
                    +"Johnny Lightning","Kustom City","Kyosho"
                    +"LandMice","Lane Exact Detail","Liberty Classics"
                    +"LJP","Luxury","Lindberg","Maisto","Minichamps"
                    +"Mira-Solido","MJX","Mondo Motors","Motor City"
                    +"Motorhead","Motormax","New Ray","Norev"
                    +"Paragon","Paudi","Pioneer","Phoenix Mint"
                    +"Precision Miniatures","Revell","Ricko Ricko"
                    +"RMZ City","Road Mice","Saico","Schuco","Shelby Collectibles"
                    +"Signature","So Real Concepts","SpecCast"
                    +"SunStar","Superior","Syma","True Scale"
                    +"Unique Replicas","Universal Hobbies"
                    +"Vitesse","XQ","Yat-Ming","Welly"};

    //System.out.println(diecastManuList.length);
    System.out.println("Please paste model title.");
    title = sc.nextLine();

    if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[0].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[0];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[1].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[1];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[2].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[2];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[3].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[3];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[4].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[4];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[5].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[5];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[6].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[6];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[7].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[7];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[8].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[8];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[9].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[9];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[10].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[10];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[11].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[11];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[12].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[12];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[13].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[13];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[14].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[14];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[15].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[15];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[16].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[16];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[17].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[17];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[18].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[18];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[19].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[19];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[20].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[20];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[21].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[21];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[22].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[22];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[23].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[23];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[24].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[24];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[25].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[25];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[26].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[26];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[27].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[27];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[28].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[28];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[29].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[29];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[30].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[30];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[31].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[31];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[32].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[32];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[33].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[33];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[34].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[34];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[35].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[35];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[36].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[36];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[37].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[37];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[38].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[38];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[39].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[39];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[40].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[40];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[41].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[41];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[42].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[42];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[43].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[43];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[44].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[44];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[45].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[45];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[46].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[46];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[47].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[47];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[48].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[48];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[49].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[49];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[50].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[50];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[51].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[51];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[52].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[52];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[53].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[53];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[54].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[54];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[55].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[55];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[56].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[56];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[57].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[57];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[58].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[58];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[59].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[59];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[60].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[60];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[61].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[61];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[62].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[62];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[63].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[63];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[64].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[64];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[65].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[65];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[66].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[66];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[67].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[67];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[68].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[68];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[69].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[69];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[70].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[70];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[71].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[71];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[72].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[72];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[73].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[73];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[74].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[74];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[75].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[75];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[76].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[76];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[77].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[77];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[78].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[78];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[79].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[79];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[80].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[80];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[81].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[81];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[82].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[82];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[83].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[83];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[84].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[84];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[85].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[85];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[86].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[86];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[87].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[87];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[88].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[88];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[89].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[89];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[90].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[90];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[91].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[91];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[92].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[92];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[93].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[93];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[94].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[94];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[95].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[95];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[96].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[96];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[97].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[97];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[98].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[98];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[99].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[99];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[100].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[100];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[101].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[101];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[102].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[102];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[103].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[103];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[104].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[104];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[105].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[105];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[106].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[106];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[107].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[107];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[108].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[108];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[109].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[109];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[110].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[110];}
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[111].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[111];}
    else {
        metaMake = defaultstring;
    }

    if (title.toLowerCase().contains(scaleList[0].toLowerCase()))
    { scale = scaleList[0]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(scaleList[1].toLowerCase()))
    { scale = scaleList[1]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(scaleList[2].toLowerCase()))
    { scale = scaleList[2]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(scaleList[3].toLowerCase()))
    { scale = scaleList[3]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(scaleList[4].toLowerCase()))
    { scale = scaleList[4]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(scaleList[5].toLowerCase()))
    { scale = scaleList[5]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(scaleList[6].toLowerCase()))
    { scale = scaleList[6]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(scaleList[7].toLowerCase()))
    { scale = scaleList[7]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(scaleList[8].toLowerCase()))
    { scale = scaleList[8]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(scaleList[9].toLowerCase()))
    { scale = scaleList[9]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(scaleList[10].toLowerCase()))
    { scale = scaleList[10]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(scaleList[11].toLowerCase()))
    { scale = scaleList[11]; }

    else { scale = defaultstring;}

    if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[0].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[0]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[1].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[1]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[2].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[2]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[3].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[3]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[4].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[4]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[5].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[5]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[6].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[6]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[7].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[7]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[8].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[8]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[9].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[9]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[10].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[10]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[11].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[11]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[12].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[12]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[13].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[13]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[14].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[14]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[15].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[15]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[16].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[16]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[17].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[17]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[18].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[18]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[19].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[19]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[20].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[20]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[21].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[21]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[22].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[22]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[23].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[23]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[24].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[24]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[25].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[25]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[26].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[26]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[27].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[27]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[28].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[28]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[29].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[29]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[30].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[30]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[31].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[31]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[32].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[32]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[33].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[33]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[34].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[34]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[35].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[35]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[36].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[36]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[37].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[37]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[38].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[38]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[39].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[39]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[40].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[40]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[41].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[41]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[42].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[42]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[43].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[43]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[44].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[44]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[45].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[45]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[46].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[46]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[47].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[47]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[48].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[48]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[49].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[49]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[50].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[50]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[51].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[51]; }
    else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(diecastManuList[52].toLowerCase()))
    { diecastManu = diecastManuList[52]; }
    else {
        diecastManu = defaultstring;
    }



    System.out.println("Please paste car model (e.g Skyline).");
    metaModel = sc.nextLine();


String fullOutput = "<METANAME="  + "\"DESCRIPTION\"" + "CONTENT=\"" + "Shop for " + title + " "
        + "diecast model cars at [SITE REMOVED]\"" +">" + "\n"
            + "<METANAME="  + "\"ABSTRACT\"" + "CONTENT=" + abstr + "\n"
         +  "<METANAME="  + "\"KEYWORDS\"" + "CONTENT=" + "“diecast cars, diecast " + scale + " "
                + "scale cars," + "\n" + "diecast model cars, modelcars, collectable cars, "
         + diecastManu + " diecast"
                        + " model, " + metaMake + " diecast cars, diecast " + metaModel +"\">";

System.out.println(fullOutput);

System.out.println("Press 'y' to run again.");
String asker = sc.next();
if (asker.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
{ keepRunning = true;}
else { keepRunning = false;}
}
```

}

I want to be able to rule out the line:

```
         System.out.println("Please paste car model (e.g Skyline).");
            metaModel = sc.nextLine();
```

And have that filled in automatically.

Comment: You will have to write your own logic for it :)

Comment: @BenjaminJB, you may start with `substring`

Comment: Regex, or `split` on whitespace, check if there are at least 3 elements, and take the third.

Comment: We're in software engineering country here. You have to lay down specifications. What is a word? In the sentence "I have 5 eggs; who want's to have 'm?" - what is the third word? '5' or 'eggs' ? And what is the last word? "'m" or "m" ? (note the quote) Is that even a word at all?

Comment: Too broad. Multiple answers possible. Please do some research and try something. Then come and ask us if you get stuck or something.

Comment: Edited to be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to kick start, **the code is not optimal** :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "StackOverflow wants you to show efforts";
        String[] s2 = s1.split(" ");
        System.out.println(s2[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Passive agressive? :D

Comment: `s1="I am"` == array index out of bounds

Comment: Let the OP do something :)

Comment: @ItachiUchiha true ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
String input="First Second Third";
String tok[]=input.split(" ");
input="";
for(int i=0;i<tok.length;i++)
{
 if(i!=2)
  {
   input=input+tok[i]+" ";
  }
}
System.out.println(input.trim());
```

**Output:**

```
First Second
```

**Note:** The trick is to split each word from input text and get the 3rd one out. Use `StringBuilder` instead of `String` for lengthy inputs.

Comment: You have extra space at the end